# python generator of dynamic length

Tags: python

I have this:

```
def get_set(line, n=3):
    words = line.split()
    for i in range(len(words) - n):
        yield (words[i], words[i+1], words[i+2])

for i in get_set('This is a test'):
    print(i)
```

But as you can see in the `yield` call, it's hard-coded to work with 3. How can I rewrite the `yield` line to work with whatever number is passed via the `n` kwarg?

(the code generators sets of each three consecutive words in a sentence, want it to generate whatever I pass as `n`)

Comment: Are you looking for the `grouper` recipe [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)?

Comment: @BrenBarn I suspect they are... although his implementation is fundamentally different ... (ie [1,2,3,4,5,...] => [1,2,3],[2,3,4,],...

Comment: Are you trying to [chunk the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just make a tuple out of the range

```
def get_set(line, n=3):
    words = line.split()
    for i in range(len(words) - (n-1)):
        yield tuple(words[i:i+n])
```

Note you need to iterate in range `len(words) - (n-1)` not `len(words)-n` to get all consecutive pairs.

With

```
for i in get_set('This is a very long test'):
    print(i)
```

This gives:

**n=3:**

`('This', 'is', 'a')
('is', 'a', 'very')
('a', 'very', 'long')
('very', 'long', 'test')`

**n=4:**

`('This', 'is', 'a', 'very')
('is', 'a', 'very', 'long')
('a', 'very', 'long', 'test')`

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in zip(*[words[x:] for x in range(n)]):
    yield row
```

should work I think

```
 for i in range(len(words)-n):
     yield words[i:i+n]
```

should also work ...

(cast to tuple if needed ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *slicing* on the list:

```
def get_set(line, n=3):
    words = line.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words), n):
        yield words[i:i+n]

for i in get_set('This is a test'):
    print(i)

['This', 'is', 'a']
['test']

for i in get_set('This is another very boring test', n=2):
    print(i)

['This', 'is']
['another', 'very']
['boring', 'test']
```